# Rust performance issue - High complexity code

Tags: performance, variables, rust

I bought RUST by its performance so I decided to translate one project where performance matters a lot, from JAVA 11 to Rust.

The thing is the Version written in JAVA performance pretty much better more than 3x in single thread, +10X in multi thread

***For context purpose:*** The most complex code is a function that trys to find an assigment between 2 sets, imagine that you have houses and stores, the stores have a fixed capacity and houses have necesities, you want to find the best assignment to walk less.

With all this in mind, I guess that the problem is how I use the variables, maybe clone() is called too much automatically, maybe reference access cause some unknown behavior.

Any upgrade that reduce while loop time will be great because it iterate over 5000 times. Sorry for the long code but I think everything is relevant in this case. You can't copy and paste this code if you want I can send you the git project link.

**PD:** I'm running with *cargo run --release*

```
pub fn evaluate(elem: &Element) -> EvaluatedElement {

    let p1 = properties::get_cast::<f64>("p1");
    let p2 = properties::get_cast::<usize>("p2");
    let p3 = properties::get_cast::<usize>("p3");
    let p4 = properties::get_cast::<f64>("p4");
    let p5 = properties::get_array::<usize>("p5");

    let mut kinds1 = kind1::get_map(); //almost 300 elements
    let kinds2 = = kind2::get_map(); //almost 300 elements

    let usables = elem.usables();

    for (i, &a) in usables.iter().enumerate() {
        if !a {
            &kinds1.remove(&(i + 1));
        }
    }

    let mut assignations = HashMap::new();

    for k in (1..=p2).rev() {
        let mut kinds2_sub = HashMap::with_capacity((&kinds2).len());
        for (_, p) in kinds2.iter() {
            if p.val1[k - 1] == 0 {
                continue;
            }

            &kinds2_sub.insert(p.id, Kind2Sub {
                parent: p.clone(),
                val2: p.val1[k - 1],
                val3: std::f64::MAX,
                kind1_id: std::usize::MAX,
            });
        }

        let mut opt_kind1_id: Option<usize> = Option::None;

        while !&kinds2_sub.is_empty() {//arround 5500 times loop

            for mut l in kinds2_sub.values_mut() {
                match opt_kind1_id {
                    None => (),
                    Some(id) => if !l.kind1_id == id { continue; },
                }

                l.val3 = std::f64::MAX;
                l.kind1_id = std::usize::MAX;

                for b in kinds1.values_mut() {
                    let dist_b_l = calc_dist(b.id, l.id);
                    if dist_b_l > p4
                        || (p1 as usize).min(l.val2) > p4 + b.val3
                        || b.val2 < k
                        || (l.val2 < (2 * p4) && (b.val3 as i16 - l.val2 as i16) < 0)
                    { continue; }

                    let tmp = dist_b_l * p1.min(l.val2 as f64);

                    if l.val3 > tmp {
                        l.val3 = tmp;
                        l.kind1_id = b.id;
                    }
                }
            }

            let lc = kinds2_sub.values_mut().min_by(|x, y| x.val3.partial_cmp(&y.val3).unwrap()).unwrap();
            let obc = kinds1.get_mut(&lc.kind1_id);
            let bc = obc.unwrap_or_else(|| {
                panic!("No assignation able")
            });
            let b_c_id = (*bc).id;
            let l_c_id = (*lc).id;

            let time = if lc.val2 < (2usize * p1 as usize) { lc.val2 } else { p1 as usize };
            let val = (*bc).val3 as i16 - time as i16;

            let assignation = Assignation { kind1_id: (*bc).id, kind2_id: lc.id, val3: k, val4: 0 };
            let assignation_id = assignation.id();//id() = fn concatenate first 3 values
            if !assignations.contains_key(&assignation_id) {
                assignations.insert(assignation.id(), assignation);
            }
            let mut assignation = assignations.get_mut(&assignation_id).unwrap_or_else(|| panic!("Assignation not found {}", assignation_id));

            if val >= 0 {
                assignation.val4 += time;
                lc.val2 -= time;
                (*bc).val3 -= time;
            } else {
                assignation.val4 += (*bc).val3;
                lc.val2 -= (*bc).val3;
                (*bc).val3 = 0;
            }

            if (*bc).val3 < p4 {
                &kinds1.remove(&b_c_id);
            }

            if lc.val2 == 0 {
                &kinds2_sub.remove(&l_c_id);
            }

            opt_kind1_id = Some(b_c_id);
        }
    }


    let assignations_values = assignations.iter().map(|(_, v)| v.clone()).collect();

    EvaluatedElement::evaluation(assignations_values)
}
```

Comment: https://gitlab.fing.edu.uy/pgrado-gf/pgrado/tree/V3_RUST/V3/backend

Comment: I believe that discussions like this are too broad, and probably better suited to https://users.rust-lang.org

Comment: I thought some expert eyes could realize some mistake like the one I made, It took me more than 30hs to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I have a 4X increase.

```
        Step  Value   Time  Used Stores
RUST -> BI 90 2672540 28057 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Java -> BI 90 2672625  4704 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
FIX: -> BI 90 2672540  1093 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

- The "bug"

  ```
  match opt_kind1_id {
      None => (),
      Some(id) => if !l.kind1_id == id { continue; },
  }
  ```
- The fix

  ```
  if let Some(id) = opt_kind1_id {
      if l.kind1_id != id {
          continue;
      }
  }
  ```

This **continue** skips 90% of finding a new value